# diffrence between two records in hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, count

i have a table with 5 columns and i need to find  count column difference of top two records.
i am able to get top two records based on some condition. example,

my table  looks like:

```
name address count current_date_time
john LA      102    2019-07-12 12:24:38
peter MAC    105    2019-07-12 12:24:40
john  NY      210   2019-07-12 12:24:02
john  WD      18    2019-07-12 12:24:12
```

select query to get top two rows:

```
SELECT count 
FROM table_name 
WHERE name="john" 
ORDER BY current_date_time DESC LIMIT 2
```

it returns like:

```
count
102
18
```

but i need the difference between 102 and 18.

how can i write sub query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply `lead()` window analytic function to determine the column value of the next row.

```
SELECT count - ld as "Difference"
  FROM
 (
  SELECT count, lead(count,1,0) over (order by current_date_time desc ) as ld,
         current_date_time 
    FROM table_name 
   WHERE name="john" 
  ORDER BY current_date_time DESC LIMIT 2
 ) q
ORDER BY q.current_date_time DESC LIMIT 1
```

where for `lead(count,1,0)` `1` means offset, i.e. `1` row after, and `0` means default value.

<kbd>[Demo in PostGres](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=d103b3890a0117d1586744d5b9bd0547)</kbd>*(`hive` has similar syntax too)*

Answer (score 1):

Use lead or lag analytic function to address previous/next row ordered by some column:

For example:

```
with your_data as (
select stack(4,
'john'  ,'LA'  ,   102, '2019-07-12 12:24:38',
'peter' ,'MAC' ,   105, '2019-07-12 12:24:40',
'john'  ,'NY'  ,   210, '2019-07-12 12:24:02',
'john'  ,'WD'  ,   18 , '2019-07-12 12:24:12'
) as (name, address, count, current_date_time)
)

select prev_count-count from
(
select s.*, lag(count) over(partition by name order by current_date_time) prev_count,
       row_number() over(partition by name order by current_date_time desc) rn
  from your_data s 
  where name="john" 
)s where rn=2;
```

Returns:

```
OK
192
```